# Hide Navigation Bar in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm newer in Flex and I would like to disable the Navigation Bar and the bookmarks tab cause I need to show a lot of information so I really need to have as much space as it's possible. I do not know what I can do.
Thanks in advance,

Alicia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the navigation and bookmarks in the browser?

Depending on the content of your application, you could potentially use full screen mode, but that has some restrictions around keyboard input (only some keys are allowed such as arrow keys, enter key etc)

Otherwise you may just need to prompt the user to turn their browser to full-screen so that they can see as much of the app as possible.

Browser full-screen/maximise is different from Flash full-screen as all keyboard input is still possible.

As far as I know there wouldn't be a way to actually modify the appearance of the browser from within a Flash application.